# About double and bigdecimal precision issues

Tags: java, mybatis, bigdecimal

There is a strange problem online, but it can't be reproduced offline.

The specific problem is as follows: the value stored in the database is 107.4, the type is decimal, the value is taken by mybatis, the java type configured by mybatis is double

The following instruction:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf (the value).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).LongValue()
```

Returns:

```
10739
```

Tested locally, the result is always:

```
10740
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: could you try the folowing `long val =  the value * 100`?

Comment: The previous problem description is a bit problematic,Now up to date

Answer (score 3):

If the value is taken as `double` the value of 107.4 in the computer will already have an approximation error, as floating point values are a finite sum of (negative) powers of 2.

Now there are rounding issues, fp-strict and more, but better remove the cause, and use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`. Note that `new BigDecimal(107.4)` will not do, only `new BigDecimal("107.4")` or correcting the precision/scale oneself.

```
double value = 107.4; // Might actually be more like 107.39999987.
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(value).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Where the scale 1 corresponds with the database column definition.

Comment: FWIW, the exact value of `107.4` as double is `107.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks, I like that precise technical detail. In this case the value is a tiny bit more than the base-10 representation 107.4. `double` has a precision of around 15 digits, and here you see that a theoretical rounding on 13 decimals would give the right number (as 107 has 3 digits).